# MacBook Pro Serial Number Not Available

Tags: macos, applecare

Today, I opened up an application to see check how my battery is going along, health, etc. It said that my Mac had an unknown manufacture date and no serial. I opened up About This Mac, and saw that for some reason, it says my serial number is "Unavailable", and it doesn't show the exact model of my mac (It just shows "MacBook Pro" instead of "MacBook Pro, Retina Late 2013" like it used to, even when I click on it)

I do have the serial number written down, and checked my warranty with Apple. I do have a valid purchase date, and Apple Care for 1 more year.

I have had the display replaced under warranty a few months ago, but I am pretty sure that that did not do it.

[image: About This Mac Info]

Comment: see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/77482/what-causes-a-mac-to-lose-its-serial-number

Comment: I have checked it out, it kind of does affect me, as all of my iMessages are now gone, I can't run a hardware test, etc.

Comment: Run the following command in Terminal and check the output: `ioreg -l | awk -F\" ' /IOPlatformSerialNumber/ { print $4 } ' `

Answer (score 1):

The best way is you should ask Apple to fix this.

If you wanna DIY (WARNING: at your own risk), with a tool named **Blank Board Serializer** (ver 1.1 part number 063-7137, please google it if you want), you can set your serial number onto your Apple computer board. There are some step by step video that should be found easily on YouTube.

Steps:

1. Burn the BBS disk image to a CD/USB.
2. Boot the compute and press the option key (i.e. the Boot Picker).
3. Insert the CD/USB and select it for booting.
4. Once the Blank Board Serializer has started, follow on-screen instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance that Apple replaced the main logic board when they replaced the display?  Since you still have AppleCare, I think you should ask apple to fix this.

Comment: No, the logic board has not been replaced, only the display. I think if I have more issues with not having a serial number then I'll take it to apple. At the moment, I can't boot into a hardware test, and all my iMessages are gone